# How to build my list layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am building a layout for Android app and I need to put inside it a list with elements. This is my situation:

- The list must be in a specific part of the layout (I have already solved this)
- The list must have scroll, because will have many elements (I think I can solved this with Scroll View)
- The elements must have a specific layout (I know how to resolve this too)
- The elements must be in a specific positions inside the list, due to this fact, I think that I would have to use a Fragment which I could design, If this is correct, should i use a fragment list, or a simple fragment with list view?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a centered ListView with some margin between the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should creat a list view in xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You don't need to wrap it in a scroll view; it can scroll anyway.

**EDIT:**
You can create different layout files for each fragment if you want, and use a different margin in each layout file. So create the different layouts you need with the different margins

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/list_image_description"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:lines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, you need to create a list object, to hold the data

```
package com.jpilfold.jimp3.models;

public class ListRow {

    private String text;
    private byte[] thumbnail;


    public ListRow(String title, byte[] thumbnail) {
        this.text = title;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }


    public byte[] getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }
}
```

Then, create an adapter to display your list

```
private List<CustomListRow> rows;
private SQLHelper helper;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<CustomListRow> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    rows = objects;
    helper = new SQLHelper(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomListRow row = this.rows.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.task.cancel(true);
    }

    if (row != null) {
        holder.title.setText(row.getTitle());
        holder.icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.task = new LoadImageTask(holder);
        holder.task.execute(row);
    }
    return view;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView icon;
    TextView title;
    LoadImageTask task;
}

private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<CustomListRow, Void, Bitmap> {

    private ViewHolder v;

    public LoadImageTask(ViewHolder v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(CustomListRow... row) {
        String imagePath = row[0].getFilePath();
        if (!isCancelled() && imagePath != null) {
            byte[] bytes = helper.findThumbnail(imagePath);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (!isCancelled() && bitmap != null) {
            v.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            v.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.albumart);
        }
        v.spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        v.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
And finally, in your ListFragment, create a list of these list rows, and add them in the order you want them displayed. You can have different fragments using different size margins like so:

BigMarginFragment

```
List<ListRow> rows = new ArrayList<ListRow>();

rows.add(new ListRow("My first item", someImage));
....

setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter, R.layout.big_margin_list_item, rows));
```

LittleMarginFragment:

```
List<ListRow> rows = new ArrayList<ListRow>();

rows.add(new ListRow("My first item", someImage));
....

setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter, R.layout.little_margin_list_item, rows));
```

And here is the finished list

[image]

Comment: Yes, It is a good solution, I am going to build it and then I will comment this answer.

Comment: I need a specific margin between elements, and this margin cannot be the same in all screen, so for this reason I think that I would have to create a fragment or a list fragment, do you agree with me?

Comment: EDIT: okay, I think I understand what you mean. So, you may may have one screen where all elements use a 20px margin, and another screen where they all use a 10px margin? Is that right?

Comment: No, I don't need a fragment for each single item, I need a fragment for the list.

Comment: @Alberto, Okay, yes you can use different fragments for different lists-- that's fine. Make sure you extend ListFragment, not Fragment. Then, in your fragment with the big margins, you can write setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter, R.layout.list_item_with_big_margins, rows)); and in the fragment with small margins, you can write setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter, list_item_with_small_margins, rows)); Then, you only need to create different layout files for the different margins.

Comment: Yes, I needed this solution, I didn't know if i could use a listfragment for this purpose. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's fine, no probs. I've updated my answer to include the changes

Comment: Thanks, Do you know if I could do this?:   layout-sw600dp (folder) > layout.xml (I use it for all tablet screens) and inside layout-sw600dp, layout-720dp I put specific list fragment for different screen sizes with the same name, so the layout.xml of layout-sw600dp could recognize the correct fragment or I must use different folder layouts. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using Fragments as items in a ListView. Fragments are for creating a more dynamic UI within your Activity, and also contain their own lifecycle.

More on Fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Please see user184994's answer on how you should correctly implement ListViews using the ArrayAdapter

The Android API guides also offer a good explanation of AdapterViews and binding data to them

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

Comment: I don't want to use a fragment for each single item of the list, I want to use the fragment for the list because I need and specific margin between elements, and this margin cannot be the same for every screen sizes, so I think that I would have to create a fragment or a list fragment, do you agree with me? @jmcdonnell40

Comment: Do you know up front what the margins will be for particular items? If so, Android allows you to provide dimension resources as described here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

To reference your dimension resources in the code, use the following:

`context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.your_dimension);`